# `Exam` class -- \bonusquestion produces strange formatting

Tags: exam

This code

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

 \fullwidth{\large Extra credit: define each of the terms below.}

        \bonusquestion [0.25] Irony

        \fillwithdottedlines{1in}

        \bonusquestion [0.25] In medias res

        \fillwithdottedlines{1in}

        \bonusquestion [0.25] Femme fatale

        \fillwithdottedlines{1in}

        \bonusquestion [0.25] Theme

        \fillwithdottedlines{1in}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

produces this result:

[image: Weird point value display]

Why am I getting that weird repeated series of point values, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: As far as I know the exam class doesn't allow for using anything else but digits and `\half` when using `addpoints` - the dot in your quarter-points will mess things up. See further the exam-manual, chapter 4.7

Comment: If you remove the [addpoints] option to documentclass, if behaves much better.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The exam class requires that the points are given with either digits or `\half`, or a combination of those when using the option `addpoints`. The problem with your code is the dot in `0.25`. More info is available in the manual for the exam class, chapter 4.7.